# SBT doesn't reconize junit testcase written in java file

Tags: scala, testing, junit, sbt

I made a Scala/Java mixed project with SBT 0.11.2. My config for JUnit testing is

```
resolvers += "twitter.com" at "http://maven.twttr.com/"

seq(com.github.retronym.SbtOneJar.oneJarSettings: _*)

libraryDependencies += "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.10-M2" % "test"
```

When I write JUnit test cases in Scala with `@Test`, every goes well. But when I write a Java JUnit test case, then run `test` in sbt, the Java JUnit test cannot be reconized. Only test cases written in Scala are executed.

How can I make sbt recognize my Java and Scala test cases at the same time?

Comment: Related question about how to add JUnit support to SBT https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28174243/run-junit-tests-with-sbt

Answer (score 9):

Probably late for the origional question, but..

I've just been looking at this. The JUnit tests in my project were not running for me until I ran `sbt clean test`. Now all working like a charm.

Comment: Wow, thanks, it's the only thing that helped me. It seems that the problem still exists for sbt 0.13.5.

Comment: Glad it helped. It was the only solution that worked for me too!  Could be the answer? :-)

Comment: Of course! If only I was an author of this question I would accept it ;)

Answer (score 3):

There was a bug in 0.11.x in detecting Java tests that was [fixed in 0.12.0](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/commit/2525eeb7e66a6f95392bb33209cc111cc9986240), although I didn't think it affected detecting annotated tests.  You might try coming up with a minimal test case and checking with the latest sbt version (0.12.1).  If the problem still exists, file a bug.

Comment: Thanks. Upgraded to 0.12.1 solved this problem. ps: Scala version should also be upgraded to 2.9.2

Answer (score 1):

you should put your test classes into src/test/java and your class name should end with "Test" (for example myTest.java)

Comment: I checked and this doesn't work. I am using JUnit4 annotation @Test. There is no need to rename class or method with a Test suffix.