# Run JUnit tests with SBT

Tags: unit-testing, junit, sbt

I have a 0.13.7 SBT project, with several sub-projects.

One of them is called `webapp`, and it has many `JUnit` tests in `webapp/src/test/java`.

When running:

```
sbt webapp/test
```

only the `ScalaTest` tests are run, but no JUnit tests.

Snippet of my `build.sbt` file:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % Test
)

lazy val webapp = project
    settings(
        Seq(
            projectDependencies ++= Seq(
                ....
                "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.2" % Test,
                "junit" % "junit" % "4.11" % Test,
                "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % Test
            )
        ): _*
    )
```

Example JUnit test:

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class CodificadorBase64Test {
    @Test
    public void testPlain() {
        byte b[] = {64, 127, 72, 36, 100, 1, 5, 9, 123};
        assertEquals("QH9IJGQBBQl7", CodificadorBase64.encode(b));
    }
}
```

**UPDATE** (some more research):

```
> webapp/testFrameworks
[info] List(TestFramework(WrappedArray(org.scalacheck.ScalaCheckFramework)), TestFramework(WrappedArray(org.specs2.runner.Specs2Framework, org.specs2.runner.SpecsFramework)), TestFramework(WrappedArray(org.specs.runner.SpecsFramework)), TestFramework(WrappedArray(org.scalatest.tools.Framework, org.scalatest.tools.ScalaTestFramework)), TestFramework(WrappedArray(com.novocode.junit.JUnitFramework))

show webapp/loadedTestFrameworks
[info] Map(TestFramework(WrappedArray(
  org.scalatest.tools.Framework, 
  org.scalatest.tools.ScalaTestFramework)
) -> org.scalatest.tools.Framework@65767aeb)
```

So `JUnit` support is known by SBT but not loaded.

Debug output:

```
[debug] Framework implementation 'org.scalacheck.ScalaCheckFramework' not present.
[debug] Framework implementation 'org.scalacheck.ScalaCheckFramework' not present.
[debug] Framework implementation 'org.scalacheck.ScalaCheckFramework' not present.
[debug] Framework implementation 'org.scalacheck.ScalaCheckFramework' not present.
[debug] Framework implementation 'org.specs2.runner.Specs2Framework' not present.
[debug] Framework implementation 'org.specs2.runner.Specs2Framework' not present.
[debug] Framework implementation 'org.specs2.runner.Specs2Framework' not present.
[debug] Framework implementation 'org.specs2.runner.Specs2Framework' not present.
[debug] Framework implementation 'org.specs2.runner.SpecsFramework' not present.
[debug] Framework implementation 'org.specs2.runner.SpecsFramework' not present.
[debug] Framework implementation 'org.specs2.runner.SpecsFramework' not present.
[debug] Framework implementation 'org.specs2.runner.SpecsFramework' not present.
[debug] Framework implementation 'org.specs.runner.SpecsFramework' not present.
[debug] Framework implementation 'org.specs.runner.SpecsFramework' not present.
[debug] Framework implementation 'org.specs.runner.SpecsFramework' not present.
[debug] Framework implementation 'org.specs.runner.SpecsFramework' not present.
[debug] Framework implementation 'com.novocode.junit.JUnitFramework' not present.
[debug] Framework implementation 'com.novocode.junit.JUnitFramework' not present.
[debug] Framework implementation 'com.novocode.junit.JUnitFramework' not present.
[debug] Framework implementation 'com.novocode.junit.JUnitFramework' not present.
[debug] Subclass fingerprints: List((org.scalatest.Suite,false,org.scalatest.tools.Framework$$anon$1@3ad42aff))
[debug] Subclass fingerprints: List((org.scalatest.Suite,false,org.scalatest.tools.Framework$$anon$1@97f54b))
[debug] Annotation fingerprints: List((org.scalatest.WrapWith,false,org.scalatest.tools.Framework$$anon$2@6a589982))
[debug] Annotation fingerprints: List((org.scalatest.WrapWith,false,org.scalatest.tools.Framework$$anon$2@1b95d5e6))
[debug] Subclass fingerprints: List((org.scalatest.Suite,false,org.scalatest.tools.Framework$$anon$1@5c997dac))
[debug] Subclass fingerprints: List((org.scalatest.Suite,false,org.scalatest.tools.Framework$$anon$1@406c43ef))
[debug] Annotation fingerprints: List((org.scalatest.WrapWith,false,org.scalatest.tools.Framework$$anon$2@282ddefc))
[debug] Annotation fingerprints: List((org.scalatest.WrapWith,false,org.scalatest.tools.Framework$$anon$2@4400c80))
```

Working with:

- SBT 0.13.9, and
- JUnit 4.x.

Related information:

- [Why don't junit tests get executed with "sbt test"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23974840/why-dont-junit-tests-get-executed-with-sbt-test)
- [SBT documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Testing.html)

Comment: Related question about how to add JUnit support to SBT https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28174243/run-junit-tests-with-sbt

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Finally, I've discovered, that I have to add the following settings to the subproject:

```
lazy val webapp = project
    settings(
        Seq(
            projectDependencies ++= Seq(
                ....
                "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.2" % Test,
                "junit" % "junit" % "4.11" % Test,
                crossPaths := false,
                "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % Test
            )
        ): _*
    )
```

It is important to declare the `junit-interface` dependency in the subproject, and in addition, to set to false the `crossPaths` setting.

The clue has been given by [this issue](https://github.com/sbt/junit-interface/issues/35).

If the main project doesn't have `JUnit` tests, then the needed test settings, don't need to be provided.

In addition, for knowing the failing method and the cause, we need this setting:

```
testOptions in Test := Seq(Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.JUnit, "-a"))
```

Comment: For me it was reverse, `sbt test` work when `crossPaths := true`. So it is depends

Answer (score 8):

This question about supporting JUnit in SBT has been asked multiple times with slightly different framings.

Multiple hits made it hard for me to find the simplest and most current answer.

[This answer by @david.perez seems clear and works with current (2018) SBT 1.1.4.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28051194/1148030)

(That particular question was about conflicting JUnit versions. The `exclude("junit", "junit-dep")` may not be necessary.)

I'll also copy-paste the code here for quick access:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "junit" % "junit" % "4.12" % Test,
  "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % Test exclude("junit", "junit-dep")
)
```