# Error on jUnit test with SBT

Tags: java, scala, junit, apache-spark, sbt

I have an error when i try to create a jUnit Test that is on my SBT Project, with Spark, Scala ...

this is my main buil.sbt:

```
name := "preowned-kittens"

val gitHeadCommitSha = taskKey[String]("Deteerminta el commit actual de git - SHA")

val makeVersionProperties = taskKey[Seq[File]]("hacer una archivo llamado version.properties.")

def PreownedKittenProject(name: String): Project = (
  Project(name, file(name)).
    settings(
      scalaVersion  := "2.11.7",
      version       := "1.0",
      organization  := "com.preowned-kittens",
      libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        "org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % "3.7" % "test",
        "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % "test"
      )
    )
  )

gitHeadCommitSha in ThisBuild := Process("git rev-parse HEAD").lines.head

lazy val common = (
  PreownedKittenProject("common")
    settings(
    makeVersionProperties := {
      val propFile = new File((resourceManaged in Compile). value, "version.properties")
      val content = "version=%s" format (gitHeadCommitSha.value)
      IO.write(propFile, content)
      Seq(propFile)
    },
    resourceGenerators in Compile <+= makeVersionProperties
    )
  )

lazy val analytics = (
  PreownedKittenProject("analytics")
    dependsOn(common)
    settings()
  )

lazy val website = (
  PreownedKittenProject("website")
    dependsOn(common)
    settings()
  )
```

and those are the libraries that i'm using on my analitics/build.sbt:

libraryDependencies += "junit" % "junit" % "4.11" % "test"

libraryDependencies += "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11"

And my Java test is this:

**LogicJavaTest.java**

```
package org.preownedkittens;

import org.junit.*;
import scala.collection.immutable.*;

public class LogicJavaTest {
    @Test
    public void testKitten() {
        Kitten kitten = new Kitten(1, new HashSet());
        // in chapter 5 we have Assert.assertEquals(1, kitten.attributes().size());
        // but as part of the chapter, we correct it - this test should pass
        Assert.assertEquals(0, kitten.attributes().size());
    }
}
```

And i having this problem when i run my test:

```
[error] /Users/juliovg/Documents/trabajo/Desarrollos/Sbt/pruebas/sbtPractice/analytics/src/test/java/org/preownedkittens/LogicJavaTest.java:13:  scala.collection.immutable.HashSet cannot be converted to scala.collection.Seq<java.lang.String>
[error] new HashSet()
[info] Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
[error] (analytics/test:compileIncremental) javac returned nonzero exit code
[error] Total time: 8 s, completed 18-feb-2016 10:18:09
```

What could be my problem.

Thanks

Comment: What's the code for the Kitten class? You're passing a HashSet as a second parameter, it's expecting a Seq...

Comment: can you see my answer ? - Thanks

Comment: why do you write an answer that is just a complement to your question? Edit the question

Comment: Related question about how to add JUnit support to SBT https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28174243/run-junit-tests-with-sbt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to pass a Java Set to a constructor expecting a Scala Seq, which is an ordered sequence. You should at least try to pass a Java List, or change the Kitten class.

See http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/conversions-between-java-and-scala-collections.html for more information about converting between Java and Scala collections.