# sbt fails to execute JUnit test

Tags: scala, junit, sbt

I'm trying to execute JUnit test

> sbt test
>
> sbt clean test

Test fails with error :

```
[info] Updating {file:/D:/sbt_projects/hello-word-ec/}hello-word-ec...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 2 Scala sources to D:\sbt_projects\hello-word-ec\target\scala-2.10\test-classes...
[error] D:\sbt_projects\hello-word-ec\src\test\scala\Test1.scala:1: object junit is not a member of package org
[error] import org.junit.Test
[error]            ^
[error] D:\sbt_projects\hello-word-ec\src\test\scala\Test1.scala:3: not found: type Test
[error]   @Test
[error]    ^
[error] D:\sbt_projects\hello-word-ec\src\test\scala\Test2.scala:1: object junit is not a member of package org
[error] import org.junit.Test
[error]            ^
[error] D:\sbt_projects\hello-word-ec\src\test\scala\Test2.scala:2: object junit is not a member of package org
[error] import org.junit.BeforeClass
[error]            ^
[error] D:\sbt_projects\hello-word-ec\src\test\scala\Test2.scala:6: not found: type BeforeClass
[error]   @BeforeClass
[error]    ^
[error] D:\sbt_projects\hello-word-ec\src\test\scala\Test2.scala:12: not found: type Test
[error]   @Test
[error]    ^
[error] 6 errors found
[error] (test:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Jul 28, 2016 6:10:04 PM
```

My build.sbt file content

```
name := "sbt junit test project"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.10.5"
libraryDependencies += "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.8" % "test->default"
libraryDependencies += "junit" % "junit" % "4.12" % Test
EclipseKeys.withSource := true
```

file %USERDIR%.sbt\0.13\plugins\build.sbt looks like

```
resolvers += Classpaths.typesafeResolver
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")
```

Comment: Related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28174243/run-junit-tests-with-sbt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put build.sbt in root project folder otherwise `sbt clean` cannot see the build.sbt and download dependencies . Originally build.sbt was located in `<project root>\project\` folder