# how to run java/scala unit test in sbt

Tags: java, scala, unit-testing, sbt

I am new to the scala,
scala project contains both scala and java unit test cases.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import itest.Level2;
    @RunWith(Suite.class)
    @Suite.SuiteClasses({Level2.class}) // Level2.class is contains @test method
    class  OrganizationRegexModelComponentTester  implements ITest{
    
    }
```

itest.jar contains  file Level2.class.
i added

```
libraryDependencies += "junit" % "junit" % "4.11" % "test" // already added
libraryDependencies += "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % "test"

testOnly company.extraction.api.util.TestJunitTwo 
[info] ScalaTest
[info] Run completed in 313 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 0
[info] Suites: completed 0, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 0, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] No tests were executed.
[info] Passed: Total 0, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 0
[success] Total time: 7 s, completed Nov 24, 2021 1:17:53 PM
```

when i run - `sbt test`  it is running only scala tests not java tests.
how to run both java and scala tests to run.

Comment: Probably related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28174243/run-junit-tests-with-sbt .  Your `sbt test` is running ScalaTest which is NOT based on JUnit.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: try to remove `@RunWith(Suite.class)`

Comment: Yes removed @RunWith(Suite.class) and added           import org.junit.experimental.categories.Categories
 @RunWith(classOf[Categories]) is working fine now